# How to filter data in Google Charts to be able to show separate/total data?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am new to Google Visualization and charts. So far no luck trying to find an answer.
I have an array of data which contains customerId, sum of invoices, date. Example of data:

```
var data = [
            [1, 500, Sun Mar 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)],
            [1, 600, Sat Aug 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)],
            [3, 800, Sat Aug 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)],
            [6, 900, Fri May 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)]
           ]
```

etc.
Alternatively, data can be also grouped by customer id like:

```
var data = [
    {customerId: 1,
     data: [
            [500, Sun Mar 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)],
            [600, Sat Aug 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)]
           ]
    },
    {customerId: 3,
     data: [[800, Sat Aug 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)]]
    },
    {customerId: 6,
     data: [[900, Fri May 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)]]
]
```

The question is whether it is possible to create a column chart with the following requirements:

a) By default the chart shows the sum of invoices from all customers on a given month ( in the data from example: March 500, May 900, August 1400)

b) There is e.g. category selector or similar which allows to select the customer name from the list and the chart will display only the selected customer's invoice data (customer name is retrieved using customerId).

So the question is in which form should the data be? Is my idea possible to implement without redrawing the graph all over with different source? Because so far the only solution I see is to set a `select` which contains customer names and ids and whenever something is selected, the program searches for customerId (in grouped data), gets the numbers, redraws the chart. But I wonder if there is a simpler or more efficient way to implement the required functionality.

Comment: @WhiteHat my point is how to toggle between displaying total data and each customer data. Like, I understand how to display data for each customer using category filter but when I also need to get the total numbers, that's where I'm stuck

Comment: you can use the [`group()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data) to find the total, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45798370/5090771)...